# Subscribing to Mono<Void> from reactive one-way handlers in SI

Tags: spring-integration, project-reactor

I've been working with project Reactor for a while but I'm fairly new to SI, specially when it comes to using reactive components in SI.
This might be very basic but I can't still figure it out and the more I read the Spring docs the less I understand.

I have this flow where I'm using a reactive adapter that returns Mono<Void>.
And as I understand, once you're using a handler/gateway that returns either `void` or `Mono<Void>` (one-way 'MessageHandler') then that signals the end of the flow and you can't add anything else downstream.
So that leaves me with this:

```
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow(AdapterThatReturnsMonoVoid adapter) {
    return f -> f
     // transformations, routing and other stuff..
     .handle(adapter::handleMessage)      
  }
```

Now. How will the subscription to that Mono be done?
What if I want to subscribe with a channel to that Mono?
Even if the Mono is not emitting any items I'd like to be able to subscribe to the completion signal.

If for example I use the `MongoDb.reactiveOutboundChannelAdapter(...)`, when I run the flow, I can see that the payload is in fact being stored in mongo. So I assume the subscription is being done automatically?

I guess my intention would be to get some kind of receipt that the operation was done.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MongoDb.reactiveOutboundChannelAdapter(...)` is represented by the `ReactiveMongoDbStoringMessageHandler` wrapped to the `ReactiveMessageHandlerAdapter` to really make that subscription automatically.

Actually the same is going to happen to any `Publisher` reply if service activator is marked as `async`. So, if your `adapter::handleMessage` returns `Mono<Void>`, you can do it like this and you'll get a completion of that `Mono`:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow reactiveStore() {
        return f -> f
                .<Object>handle((p, h) -> Mono.empty(),
                        e -> e.async(true)
                                .customizeMonoReply((message, mono) ->
                                        mono.doOnSuccess(data -> System.out.println("Completed: " + data))));
    }
```

And I get this in logs:

```
Completed: null
```

I probably need to revise a `ReactiveMessageHandlerAdapter` because it looks like any `ReactiveMessageHandler` can be handled directly and more smoothly. Please, raise a GH issue so we don't lose our discussion.

Meanwhile here are docs to clarify you more:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/reactive-streams.html#reactive-message-handler

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#reactive-advice

Comment: That's great. I appreciate the help @artem-bilan ! Will do about raising the issue on GH

Comment: Sure. Sorry about that. I'm a newbie and it doesn't let me vote yet, but I just accepted it